# Excel 2010 VBA highlight with different colors cells with different duplicate values across several columns

Tags: vba, excel

How do I highlight with different colors duplicate cells in Excel 2010 across multiple columns?

I found this code but it works for one column.

```
    Sub Highlight_Duplicate_Entry()
        Dim cel As Variant
        Dim myrng As Range
        Dim clr As Long
    
        Set myrng = Range("A2:A" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
        myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        clr = 3

        For Each cel In myrng
           If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cel) > 1 Then
              If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A" & cel.Row), cel) = 1 Then
                 cel.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
                 clr = clr + 1
              Else
                 cel.Interior.ColorIndex = myrng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, myrng, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
              End If
          End If
       Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please use conditional formatting in excel

Comment: Conditional formatting will highlight all duplicates with the same color. OP wants to highlight each set of duplicates in a different color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the range to cover multiple columns, which will cause your `Match` function to fail. Replace it with `Find`. The sub below will find any duplicates in the specified range and highlight them with a different color.

Replace your code with the following:

```
Sub Highlight_Duplicate_Entry()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim myrng As Range
    Dim clr As Long
    Dim lastCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set myrng = ws.Range("A2:d" & Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    With myrng
        Set lastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With
    myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    clr = 3

    For Each cell In myrng
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cell) > 1 Then
            ' addresses will match for first instance of value in range
            If myrng.Find(what:=cell, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, after:=lastCell).Address = cell.Address Then
                ' set the color for this value (will be used throughout the range)
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
                clr = clr + 1
            Else
                ' if not the first instance, set color to match the first instance
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = myrng.Find(what:=cell, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, after:=lastCell).Interior.ColorIndex
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Adding a screen shot of the result based on a comment below to help clarify how this works. Each set of duplicates is highlighted in a separate color. Values that aren't duplicates are not colored:
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your help, but the code doenst work for some numbers that are not highlighted. Could you provide more help to solve my problem?

Comment: Thank you a lot, but for duplicate numbers in same row, the code didn't get. My data range (only numeric inputs) has unique numbers in columns but not in rows.

Comment: Try now. It should now work for all of the cases you need it to.

Comment: perfect. But... please... last thing. How can I determine the column with last used row, because some columns have more rows than others,then I put, for example, C in ...Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count)... - 8th line,because C is the Column that has more rows. Thank you very,very much!!!

Comment: You did it the right way. Glad it worked for you. You can automate that part as well. If you search SO for "find last row excel vba" you should find a bunch of helpful options.

Comment: A message "Vote up requires 15 reputation", sorry but I think I can't

Comment: @JonCrowell -I'm not quite understanding how to use this?

Comment: @MAW74656: I added a screen shot. Does that help?

Comment: @JonCrowell -Thanks, but not exactly.  I've figured it out since, but what I wanted to hear was "call it from the view macro's screen".