# Delete Cell based on Color Index

Tags: vba, excel

I have data which shows me duplicates between two lists. I'm trying to delete the cells which have duplication to only show me the ones that don't match. Therefore, I can't delete rows but can only delete cells to achieve what I'm trying. I tried the Find Duplication built in funcition but it's not working.

This is what my sheet looks like: [image: http://i.imgur.com/SLlq7l6.png]

I've found this code [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/VBA/21970.html):

```
Sub RowDelete()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim myRow As Integer
Dim myCol As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer

Counter = 0
myCol = 1
rBegin = 1
rEnd = 100

For myRow = rEnd To rBegin Step -1
Application.StatusBar = Counter & " rows deleted."
If Cells(myRow, myCol).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
Cells(myRow, myCol).EntireRow.Delete
Counter = Counter + 1
End If
Next myRow
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
x = MsgBox(Counter & " rows deleted.", vbOKOnly, "Rows Deleted")

End Sub
```

I need help altering it to delete only cells and not Rows which have this format:

```
With formatCols.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With formatCols.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

Comment: Do you want to delete the value and move the others up? Or do you simply want to delete the contents of the cell?

Comment: I'm trying to delete the cell and shift it up, that way at the end I have a good enough looking list without blanks in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sub will delete any cells in the `dupeColumn` if they have `.Interior.Color = 13551615`. If you also need to check the font, you can modify the condition that must be met before the cell is deleted.

Note that when you are using a loop to delete cells or rows from a range, you need to start at the bottom and work your way up to prevent the need to figure out where you are after a deletion.

You can use this for as many columns you want. Set the upper range of the `For` loop in the `DeleteDupesForAllColumns` to the last column you want to process.

```
Sub DeleteDupesForAllColumns()
    Dim dupeColumn As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For dupeColumn = 1 To 5
        Call DeleteDupesBasedOnColor(dupeColumn)
    Next dupeColumn
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub DeleteDupesBasedOnColor(dupeColumn As Long)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim firstRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    firstRow = 1
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, dupeColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
        Set cell = ws.Cells(i, dupeColumn)
        If cell.Interior.Color = 13551615 Then
            cell.Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Note:** Make sure you set the variables to the objects you want to work with. (e.g. set the ws to the sheet that has the duplicate column, and set dupeColumn to the correct column)

**EDIT:** It is very difficult to detect the color in a cell that is based on conditional formatting. If that is how the colors in your cells are set, you can use the following sub to set the duplicate cells' interior color to something you can then detect using the code above. Run this first and then run `DeleteDupesForAllColumns()`.

```
Sub ColorDupeCells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dupeRange As Range
    Dim dupeColor As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set dupeRange = ws.Range("A2:K100")

    dupeRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    dupeColor = 13551615

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In dupeRange
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dupeRange, cell) > 1 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = dupeColor
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You may also be interested in [highlighting each set of duplicates in a range with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15177752/138938).

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to just work on all columns in use? My sheet currently go from A1:JS88. Basically all duplications within that range is what I'm trying to eliminate. From the picture in OP, basically everything in pink.

Comment: So if my sheet is called users, I just need to change:Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("users")?

Comment: I ran it but nothing happened

Comment: Doh! Needed to qualify `Cells` with `ws.` prefix. Try with my edit.

Comment: Hey, so I went to A1 and ran it from there, not sure if that matters, I doubt it. Anyways. I got, script out of range error. The only thing I changed was setting the sheet to "userBk1" when setting WS. Do I need to select the range?

Comment: Type this in your Immediate window: `? sheets("userBk1").name` and tell me what happens.

Comment: Type it into a cell? Also I think the problem is that I didn't set the number of columns in DeleteDupesForAllColumns. If I need it to go from A to LT, how's the syntax work for that?

Comment: Your immediate window is in the VBA editor. Type the command in there. Column A = 1, B = 2, etc. LT is 332.

Comment: Ok well I put it right under Sub DeleteDupesForAllColumns() and it changes to a Print function. Then when i ran it I got subscript out of range. Also for the number of columns you already set it from 1-5 right. So I'd just need to change 5 to 332 or whatever I need.

Comment: I found the immediate window, it gave me: usersBk1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32297/discussion-between-head-of-catering-and-batman)

Comment: The HighlightDupeCells function, are you looking at all the cells in the range for duplicates because the way my data is formatted I'm going by 2 for the comparison. I'm comparing AnB, CnD, EnF. The names in the lists repeat throughout the sheet, if I compare between the entire range, it's likely all will duplicate which isn't what I'm trying to do.

Comment: In that case you'll need to set the range to A and B, run the code, remove dupes, then set the range to C and D and so forth.

Comment: I had this code which applied the conditional formatting across my sheet automatically by 2 cells. Is there a way to modify this to do what you're trying to do? With 300+ columns, going manually isn't really an options. This is what I used for conditional formatting. http://jsfiddle.net/K7puR/

Comment: You can use a loop to do it automatically, scooting over 2 columns at a time. If you need help setting that up, post another question.