# VBA Highlight different duplicates with different colors across a table array

Tags: excel, vba

My question is in the title. I have searched up everywhere and this one feels like the only answer that is working:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15180079/17038705

I have created a sample Excel file and validated that his VBA code works, the sample he shows looks like it is working too. However, when I ran it with the Excel file I am working on, I got Error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set.

[image]

After some digging, it is probably because of his Find() function that returns Nothing.

[image]

My question is why this is the case for my file and not for others. The values there are based on formulas and values of other cells, would that be a problem?

Other approaches are appreciated as well. Thanks!

Comment: I guess it cannot find whatever the value of `cell` is... the simple solution it to check to see if the `Find` returns `Nothing` before trying to check the `.Address`. When you get the error, what is the value of `cell`? Is it before or after `lastCell`?

Comment: braX has guessed the most probable cause. However, without enough of your code to be able to reproduce the problem, the reason that's happening (or in fact if something else is happening ) is impossible to tell. Also, can you please not post images of code. Instead post your actual code, as code in your question (see editing help on how to do that).

Comment: @braX : I added a line, something like "If myrng.Find(..) is Nothing Then pass" and it never goes to the next line anymore. So I guess that means they all return Nothing.

Comment: @Spinner : Oh my bad. I only added the image to show at which point the code raises the error. The code is the same as in the link attached.

Comment: Still not enough info to work out what's wrong (as can't tell if the range used there matches you range in you data (as you're not showing row and column info.

Comment: As for other approaches: Personally, I would recommend avoiding use of find. It's inherently harder to work with than other methods. Simplest method for this type of thing is: `For each rgCell in rgSearch.Cells` where `rgCell` and `rgSearch` are range variables and rgSearch is set to the cells you wish to process (aka myrange in your example). Then simply compare per `if rgCell = vnVal then` where `vnVal` is the value you're comparing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data contains formulas, you need to set the `LookIn` parameter to `xlValues` in the `Find` method. I updated the original code with these changes, take a look:

```
Sub Highlight_Duplicate_Entry()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim myrng As Range
    Dim clr As Long
    Dim lastCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set myrng = ws.Range("A2:D" & Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    With myrng
        Set lastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With
    myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    clr = 3

    For Each cell In myrng
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cell) > 1 Then
            ' addresses will match for first instance of value in range
                                    '[================]
            If myrng.Find(what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, after:=lastCell).Address = cell.Address Then
                ' set the color for this value (will be used throughout the range)
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
                clr = clr + 1
            Else
                ' if not the first instance, set color to match the first instance
                                                                '[================]
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = myrng.Find(what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, after:=lastCell).Interior.ColorIndex
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach using a Dictionary to track values vs. colors:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    ColorDups Range("A1").CurrentRegion
End Sub

Sub ColorDups(rng As Range)
    Dim c As Range, dict As Object, i As Long, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    i = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = CStr(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            If Not dict.exists(v) Then
                dict.Add v, c 'store the first cell with this value
            Else
                If TypeOf dict(v) Is Range Then     'second cell with this value?
                    i = i + 1                       'next index
                    dict(v).Interior.ColorIndex = i 'color the first cell
                    dict(v) = i                     'store the index
                End If
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = dict(v)     'color this duplicate
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```